# Nested if statements vs complex logic in condition

Tags: java, nested-if

I have the following problem. I need to validate date and time, so it returns false if the day of the week is *Tuesday* or*Thursday* and the time is between 2:00 and 3:00 PM.

I have two options:

```
if (appointmentRequest.getDateTime().getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.TUESDAY
                || appointmentRequest.getDateTime().getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.THURSDAY) {
            if (appointmentRequest.getDateTime().getHour() == 2) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Option 2:

```
if ((appointmentRequest.getDateTime().getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.TUESDAY
                || appointmentRequest.getDateTime().getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)
                && (appointmentRequest.getDateTime().getHour() == 2)) {
            return false;
        }
```

What is the best practice in cases like this?

Comment: There's no definitive answer. It is more a matter of style. I find the first one to be more readable.

Answer (score 5):

Logically they are equivalent, and computationally there will be negligible difference in the run times.

Always strive for *clarity* and the one that is going to be more extensible, and simpler to maintain. As a rule of thumb, bear in mind that although you typically write a line of code once, you'll debug it hundreds of times.

My instinct is that the first option fits that. It's easy to set a line break on the second `if` if you make that choice.

Comment: Aggree, but I would create a method like verifyDayOfWeek(appointmentRequest.getDateTime()) and a similar one for Hour. That way you could have something like: if (!verifyDayOfWeek() && ! verifyHour())

Comment: @m0skit0: that is well-put. If you submit an answer on that premise I'll be sure to upvote it.

Comment: I think your answer already includes that *"Always strive for clarity"*. Just my 2 cents on it :)

Answer (score 2):

I find your question a bit of a false dichotomy; clarity can be won in other ways, for example by a combination of extracting the common subexpression into a variable and relying on `EnumSet`:

```
LocalDateTime dt = appointmentRequest.getDateTime();
if (EnumSet.of(TUESDAY, THURSDAY).contains(dt.getDayOfWeek()) && dt.getHour() == 2) {
    return false;
}
```